# Excel using python, do all users require python?

Tags: python, excel, tournament

I'm interested in creating a tournament template in excel using python, but I don't expect all my users to have python installed. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there some other easy-to-use gui that would be suitable for something like this? I've looked at addins using PyXLL and such but they seem to require all users to have them installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating a application in pyqt5 and then create exe of that script using pyinstaller

1- Use pip install pyinstaller
2- pyinstaller -onfile yourcode.py
3- this command will create yourcode.exe

yourcode.exe will run on all the machines either python is installed or not

Answer (score 1):

Implement your tournament template generator application as a web application which runs on a server. Then you can use whatever you like to develop it, and your users don't need more than a web browser to run it.

Comment: *"and your users don't need more than a web browser to run it."* That's not true; they'd also need an internet connection. Which is not required with other solutions such as an Excel worksheet or a python script.

Comment: @Stef: I think the typical reader of my answer is smart enough to figure this out by themselves ;-)